# Confusion after setting a property of a Map

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, immutability, redux, immutable.js

I'm reading and practicing the tutorial: http://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html
But I couldn't get reducer tests passed. Then I made a new test to find out the reason.

Here's the test.js(mocha with chai):

```
import {expect} from 'chai';
import {List, Map, fromJS} from 'immutable';

describe('set', () => {
  it('sets map\'s property', () => {
    const state = Map();
    const action = {type: 'SET_ENTRIES', entries: ['Trainspotting']};
    const nextState = state.set('entries', action.entries);

    /*
    expect(nextState).to.equal(Map({
      entries: ['Trainspotting']
    }));
    */
    expect(nextState).to.equal(fromJS({
      entries: ['Trainspotting']
    }));
  });
});
```

Either use Map or fromJS, the test doesn't pass

If choose "Map", it shows:

```
  AssertionError: expected 'Map { "entries": Trainspotting }' to equal 'Map { "entries": Trainspotting }'
  + expected - actual
```

If choose "fromJS", it shows:

```
  AssertionError: expected 'Map { "entries": Trainspotting }' to equal 'Map { "entries": List [ "Trainspotting" ] }'
  + expected - actual

  -Map { "entries": Trainspotting }
  +Map { "entries": List [ "Trainspotting" ] }
```

It's really confusing. How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
const nextState = state.set('entries', List(action.entries));
```

Comment: I tried it just now as you said with the second "expect" statement (fromJS). It works. But why? Does this mean the tutorial I mentioned above is wrong?

Comment: When you set your entries like that: state.set('entries', action.entries), action.entries is a simple array not an Immutable List. In other side, you can't compare it with fromJS({
      entries: ['Trainspotting']
    }).
It will create a List instance of entries. That's the power of fromJS()

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot!